# OSX open dock menu programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, dock

I have added custom items to the dock menu for my app and they are correctly displayed when the app icon in the dock is right clicked or Cmd + Clicked.

However I would like to display the same menu even if the dock icon is left-clicked.

I plan to handle this in applicationShouldHandleReopen, however I am unable to figure out how to make the dock menu load programmatically.

Any suggestions?